# Encryption/Decryption in Android with RSA

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa, genymotion

Note: due to being a new member here at stackoverflow and reputation restrictions on links, I will have to post **large** chunks of code here.

EDIT: I have since I posted this updated both my Genymotion device and my SDKs, and so far I have managed to get the decrypted byte array, but with a bunch of leading zeroes. To accomplish this I have not touched a single line of code though. Something definitely seems to be strange with the environment I am running the app on.

I have been trying to encrypt and decrypt a randomly generated AES key (along with its IV) using RSA which I then use when encrypting data transferred between a server and an android device. I have been testing my code using a Genymotion device, and that is where I have been encountering these problems so far.

The code has been tested and has worked on a desktop setup before, and the problem only started appearing when I copied over to my android project in Android Studio. I have used these encrypt and decrypt methods on a desktop setup without problems.

I think I did manage to localise the problem as being in my RSA encryption by encrypting some text and not getting the same bytes after decryption, although I can not completely rule out additional errors:

```
private byte[] decrypt(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, PRIVATE_KEY);
    return cipher.doFinal(bytes);
}

private byte[] encrypt(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, SERVER_KEY);
    return cipher.doFinal(bytes);
}

//Made this method to test my own keys, and whether or not encryption works
private byte[] encryptMyOwnKey(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, PUBLIC_KEY);
    return cipher.doFinal(bytes);
}
```

In the constructor I have just added this piece of code, to test those two methods.

```
private ServerInterface(Context context) throws IOException {
    //Some not so interesting code goes here
    final KeyPair key = getKeyPair(context);
    PRIVATE_KEY = (RSAPrivateKey) key.getPrivate();
    PUBLIC_KEY = (RSAPublicKey) key.getPublic();
    try {
        //Some dummy text for testing
        byte[] test = decrypt(encryptMyOwnKey("Decryption successful".getBytes()));
        Log.i("ServerInterface", "Test result: "+new String(test));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //More code that isn't interesting
}
```

And the methods that are used to get the KeyPair are:

```
private static KeyPair getKeyPair(Context context) {
    final File keyFileDirectory = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "rsa/");
    final File publicKeyFile = new File(keyFileDirectory, "sikkr_pub_key");
    final File privateKeyFile = new File(keyFileDirectory, "sikkr_priv_key");
    KeyPair key;

    if (publicKeyFile.exists() && privateKeyFile.exists()) {
        try {
            key = getKeyPairFromFile(publicKeyFile, privateKeyFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            key = generateKeyPair(publicKeyFile, privateKeyFile);
        }
    } else {
        key = generateKeyPair(publicKeyFile, privateKeyFile);
    }
    return key;
}

private static KeyPair getKeyPairFromFile(File publicKeyFile, File privateKeyFile) throws Exception {
    Log.d("ServerInterface", "Getting the key pair from file");
    byte[] publicKey = readByteDataFromFile(publicKeyFile);
    byte[] privateKey = readByteDataFromFile(privateKeyFile);

    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey));
    RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey));
    return new KeyPair(pubKey, privKey);
}

private static KeyPair generateKeyPair(File publicKeyFile, File privateKeyFile) {
    Log.d("ServerInterface", "Generating a key pair");
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen;
    KeyPair key = null;

    if (publicKeyFile.exists()) {
        publicKeyFile.delete();
    }

    if (privateKeyFile.exists()) {
        privateKeyFile.delete();
    }

    try {
        keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyGen.initialize(2048);
        key = keyGen.genKeyPair();

        if (!publicKeyFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
            publicKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }

        publicKeyFile.createNewFile();
        privateKeyFile.createNewFile();
        saveByteDataToFile(publicKeyFile, key.getPublic().getEncoded());
        saveByteDataToFile(privateKeyFile, key.getPrivate().getEncoded());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void saveByteDataToFile(File file, byte[] data) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    dos.write(data);
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();
}

private static void readByteDataFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    byte[] read = new byte[dis.available()];
    dis.readFully(read);
    dis.close();
    return read;
}
```

The logs that I get from running the app are:

```
10-18 13:55:16.472    1251-1265/edu.chalmers.sikkr I/ServerInterface﹕ Setting up an interface to the server
10-18 13:55:16.528    1251-1265/edu.chalmers.sikkr D/ServerInterface﹕ Generating a key pair
10-18 13:55:17.004    1251-1265/edu.chalmers.sikkr I/ServerInterface﹕ Test result: JNk9���N+!N^9__ `D�)̊#O�K��\���Q�eD�(���M�
&vK6���%M��,�9wg��!um7���t�9�w+�LGh�0ڼ{�s]���̅�����_͵b�͸-0��> ��fk@m}��Wx|�g�_��P8;��t��:��5��8��o�͐w�Ơ����o$��2��jS2�Z��j̪����j�l_HZ�k���~�����7�b��N�fޒ�Ի*)I.IE�
```

As you can see, the test result is nowhere near decrypted text, which is most likely what has caused problems for me when testing all of the functions. I am lost as to how to solve this, since most of the code has previously worked flawlessly on a desktop environment. Help would be much appreciated.

Edit: The new output I was talking about previously:

```
10-18 20:45:44.969    1301-1314/edu.chalmers.sikkr I/ServerInterface﹕ Test result: ��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������Decryption successful
```

Edit: This last problem was also solved, by changing to PKCS1Padding from NoPadding.

Answer (score 0):

In your generateKeyPair function you have:

```
saveByteDataToFile(privateKeyFile, key.getPublic().getEncoded());
```

where it should have been:

```
saveByteDataToFile(privateKeyFile, key.getPrivate().getEncoded());
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo when I copied the text from one computer to another. The original code is just as you said it should be. Still gives me the same result. Never the less, the logs doesn't even say it reads from file in this instance (because it is run for the first time) which means it should not be looking in the file for the key. I changed my original question according to your correction to avoid future confusions.